# Qt, работа приложения без оконного менеджера в xinit, проблемы с фокусом

Tags: linux, qt

В моем приложении используется самодельный виджет отрисовывающий *QPainter*' ом на себе в зависимости от своих параметров, так же на нем можно разместить другие виджеты, зажав *ctrl* и щелкнув *лкм*. Программу нужно использовать без оконного менеджера  (используя только *xinit*). Здесь возникает загвоздка, при запуске приложения на виджет не устанавливается фокус, (с оконными менеджерами пробовал, все работает)

Приложение можно отобразить на весь экран ( реализовано средствами *Qt* - *QWidget::showFullScreen()* ), в этом режиме фокус срабатывает верно, перепробовал многое, *focusPolicy* и пробовал устанавливать фокус средствами *XLib*, ничего не помогает. 
Кто нибудь может подсказать, куда копать?

Comment: Можно попробовать ставить фокус в определённую область экрана и в этой области создавать виджет.

Comment: Какую функцию и откуда для этого использовать?

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, код, в котором вы пытались использовать функцию [XSetInputFocus](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XSetInputFocus.html), укажите, как получили для неё параметры.